# c++ error linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, xcode, error-handling

Hello i got some errors on my Celsius to Fahrenheit code! first error:

> ctoc(float)", referenced from:

second error:

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float ftoc(float temp);
float ctoc(float temp);

int main() {
bool run = true;
char input;
float temp;

while (run == true) {
    cout<<"Enter F for Fahr to Celsius or C for Celsius to Fahr or E to exit.\n";
    cin>>input;

    if(input == 'e'){
        run = false;
    }   else if(input=='f'){
        cout<<"Enter the tempeature in Fahr.\n";
        cin>>temp;
        cout<<"The temperature in Celsius is "<<ftoc(temp)<<".\n\n\n";
    }   else if(input == 'c'){
        cout<<"The temperature in Fahr is "<<ctoc(temp)<<".\n\n\n";
    }   else {
        cout<<"The character you enteed wasnt valid. Please try again.\n\n\n";
    }
}
return 0;
}
float ftoc(float temp){
    return (temp-32)/1.8;
}
float ctof(float temp){
   return (temp*1.8)+32;
}
```

Comment: typo - ctoc and ctof

Comment: You're requesting an input of a single char, that wouldn't be a problem for a switch-statement in C++. Initialize temp to 0 maybe that helps! Add the two functions above the main and change ctoc to ctof.

Comment: @Lazcano Passing primitives by reference is a pessimization, as is sticking `const` on the return value.

Comment: Oh, i'll read about that. Thanks for info

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're requesting an input of a single char, that wouldn't be a problem for a switch-statement in C++. Add the two functions above the main and change ctoc to ctof.

So the code would look like that:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


float ftoc(float temp){
    return (temp-32)/1.8;
}

float ctof(float temp){
   return (temp*1.8)+32;
}

int main() {
bool run = true;
char input;
float temp;

while (run == true) {
    cout<<"Enter F for Fahr to Celsius or C for Celsius to Fahr or E to exit.\n";
    cin>>input;

    /*
        switch statement
    */

}
return 0;
}
```